# VBA iterate method calls

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to dry my code and perform an action like this:

```
dim methodNames() as String
methodNames(1) = "MethodName1"
methodNames(2) = "MethodName2"
...

for each method in methodNames
    some wrapper syntax that includes 
    "call method" and is independent of the method
    ...
next
```

is this anyhow possible? it is just that I would like to spare me copy + paste of the syntax each time.

Many greetings,
Peter

Comment: Probably - but it is a bit hard to see exactly what you are trying to do from your code. Is your issue purely with having an array of arbitrary size?

Comment: Peter, if you feel I have closed this post in error then let me know and I will open it :)

Comment: Oh, that seems like a more likely question, especially after reading the title again as well. Good answer in the linked question btw. @SiddharthRout

Comment: hi Siddharth, yes I guess that application run "method" will solve my issue. I will try and come back to you. thank you for the link.